# HTML Intellisense between Back Ticks in Typescript Files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

When editing typescript files (.ts) in VSCode is there a intellisense support of HTML between back tick characters?

This could be useful when editing template object for  @Component attribute.

Regards

Comment: If the question concerns Angular, please, rephrase it. IDE may not support HTML syntax in strings in general but may support it in component templates.

Comment: @estus : It's about writing typescript in VSCode IDE. I also tought that it wouldn't support component templates but wanted to ask though.

Comment: @Aluan : Because with single quoutes you can insert HTML with line breaks

Comment: I'm so sorry, yes you're right, back ticks. I'll edit the question now